EjsAdapter marked as Open handler in Jest test running
I am trying to run my tests on cloud using ci gh actions but due to that open handler issue the pipeline keeps loading forever and does not stop. how can I resolve that issue of EjsAdapter open handler
Error when I add --detectOpenHandles
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  CustomGC

      4 | import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
      5 | import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
    > 6 | import { EjsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/ejs.adapter';
        | ^
      7 |
      8 | import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';
      9 |

      at Runtime._loadModule (../../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1018:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@css-inline/css-inline/index.js:190:31)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../../../node_modules/@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/ejs.adapter.js:8:22)
      at Object.<anonymous> (emails/emails.module.ts:6:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (app.module.ts:9:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/users/users.service.spec.ts:3:1)

